# Tkinter .after module just delaying the opening of the GUI

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm currently programming a BlackJack game as a first project with python on a tkinter GUI.

I'm trying to use the after module to make the cards appear every second on the GUI, however this code just delays the opening of the GUI and opens with the images already in there. After many research and different tests I still get the same result.

Here is a simplified version of the code

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()


def add(image, x, y):
    canvas.create_image(x, y, image=image)


image1 = PhotoImage(file="images/AceHearts.png")
image2 = PhotoImage(file="images/AceClubs.png")
image3 = PhotoImage(file="images/AceDiamonds.png")

canvas.after(1000, add(image1, 50, 50))
canvas.after(1000, add(image2, 70, 50))
canvas.after(1000, add(image3, 90, 50))

window.mainloop()
```

The result i would expect if for the GUI to open, then have one image being added every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically calling the `add()` function and passing `None` value to all of the callbacks in these lines as `add()` returns `None`.

```
canvas.after(1000, add(image1, 50, 50))
canvas.after(1000, add(image2, 70, 50))
canvas.after(1000, add(image3, 90, 50))
```

---

Look carefully what you missing. The syntax of `after()` function is

> `after( ms, func, args )`

**Parameters of `after()`:**

1. **ms** = milliseconds
2. **func** = function with no parenthesises `()`, `after` just want the reference of the function.
3. **args** = The parameter of the function if any

Also you gave 1000ms to every `after` function which means they all get called after 1 sec.

---

### **Right way of doing it.**

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()


def add(image, x, y):
    canvas.create_image(x, y, image=image)


image1 = PhotoImage(file="images/AceHearts.png")
image2 = PhotoImage(file="images/AceClubs.png")
image3 = PhotoImage(file="images/AceDiamonds.png")

canvas.after(1000, add, image1, 50, 50)  # run after 1 sec
canvas.after(2000, add, image2, 70, 50)  # run after 2 sec
canvas.after(3000, add, image3, 90, 50)  # run after 3 sec

window.mainloop()
```